# Disable TeamCity build queuing

Tags: queue, teamcity

Is it possible to disable queuing on builds in TeamCity? If a job is already running, I don't want another one to queue (for example, if started by a trigger). I've done some searching and do not see a way to prevent the queuing up.

Comment: Usually there won't be another job running, and it'll be ok for the trigger to kick off the job, but if there is a job, i don't want the job to queue, this all happens at night.

Comment: What kind of trigger is it?

Comment: scheduled trigger. 12am everynight it'll kick off this job, but there is another job that has a chance of running, that runs all night, if this happens, i don't want the triggered job to run, because it would queue into the morning which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each is only one build configuration, you could run them on the same agent, so that way only one could run at the same time. But then, build 2 would run after build 1 finishes, which you don't want.

Here's how I solved this problem. It's kind of ugly, but it's simple, and generalizes to many build configurations:

Pick a specific server. Since this server will determine whether a build runs, we'll call it your *gate* server. We need a file location that doesn't exist now, nor will it be created by any other program. Say, for example, `/teamcity/.lock'

Make a build configuration with the following contents:

```
lockFileLocation="/teamcity/.lock"
if [ -f $lockFileLocation ];
then
    echo "oops, we're already running a build."
    exit 1
else
    echo "No build is running. Let's lock it up!"
    touch $lockFileLocation
fi
```

For Powershell, it's this:

```
$lockFileLocation = "C:\teamcity\lock"
if(Test-Path $lockFileLocation)
{
    echo "oops, we're already running a build."
    exit 1
}
else
{
    echo "No build is running. Let's lock it up!"
    echo "lock'd!" > $lockFileLocation
}
```

And make sure that build is set to run only on the *gate* agent. So this build will only succeed if it hasn't ever run. Not useful yet. Let's call this build *lock*. Make a new build configuration with the following contents:

```
lockFileLocation="/teamcity/.lock"
if [ -f $lockFileLocation ];
then
    echo "Build's over. You don't have to do home, but you can't stay here"
    rm $lockFileLocation
else
    echo "No build is running. How did we get here?"
    exit 1
fi
```

For Powershell:

```
$lockFileLocation = "C:\teamcity\lock"
if(Test-Path $lockFileLocation)
{
    echo "Build's over. You don't have to do home, but you can't stay here"        
    rm "$lockFileLocation"
}
else
{
    echo "No build is running. How did we get here?"
    exit 1
}
```

Make sure that build is set to run only on *gate*, and that build will delete the file if it exists. Let's call the build *unlock*.

Cool, now we can run *lock* to write the file, and *unlock* to delete it. If you run *lock* twice without running *unlock*, the first run of *lock* will pass, and the second will fail. Nice.

But how does this help us? Let's say that your build is a single build configuration called *work*. Set a finish build trigger on *work* so that it runs after *lock* succeeds. Similarly, set a finish build trigger on *unlock* so that it runs after *work* finishes, **whether it passes or fails**. We want to unlock the build even if you committed bad code.

If your build is a set of build configurations, your build internally needs to be connected via snapshot dependencies, and not finish build triggers. Say your build is two build configurations: *work-A* and *work-B*. You want to run *work-A* first, then when it's done, *work-B*. Set a snapshot dependency from *work-B* to *work-A* as usual. Then, set a finish build trigger on *unlock* that triggers when *lock* passes. Set a snapshot dependency from *unlock* to *work-B*, set to "run build even if dependency has failed. Here's a drawing of the build, where downward arrows are finish build triggers, and upward arrows are snapshot dependencies:

```
+----+                           
|lock|                           
+----+  +------+                 
  |     |work-A|                 
  |     +------+                 
  |        ^                     
  |        |                     
  |        |                      
   \   +------+                  
    \  |work-B|                  
     \ +------+                  
      \   ^                      
       \  |                      
        v |                      
       +------+                  
       |unlock|                  
       +------+
```

Now, when you hit "run" on *lock*, it will lock the build, trigger your build configurations, then unlock the build. Hit "run" a bunch of times, and see how neither *work-A* nor *work-B* gets queued up.

But that's only one set of build configurations. You have two. So set both of them up this way, making sure they look at the same file, and are both set to run only on the *gate* agent.

Yay! We're done! But wait, why do *work-A* and *work-B* need to be connected via snapshot dependencies? Well, let's say the build is as follows:

```
+----+
|lock|
+----+
   |
   |
   v
+------+ 
|work-A|
+------+
   |
   |
   v             
+------+
|work-B|
+------+
   |
   |
   v
+------+
|unlock|
+------+
```

Now, what if *work-A* fails? *work-B* won't run, and so neither will *unlock*.

Note: theoretically, you could run the build as follows:

```
+----+        
|lock|        
+----+  +------+
   \    |work-A|
    \   +------+
     \     ^
      \    |
       v   |
      +------+
      |work-B|
      +------+
         |    
         |    
         v   
      +------+
      |unlock|
      +------+
```

This should work, but I haven't tested it, so I can't give you all the settings.

Comment: Thank you for all your direction here, I'm going to give this a try and will respond here as well with my results.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to dynamically disable a trigger or conditionally run one build based on the status of another.

If these two jobs are unrelated to one another, perhaps you could configure them to run on separate agents?  That way they could run without interfering with one another.

Comment: These two jobs would interfere with each other so I can't let them run together. Thanks for looking into it.